# Deleting all objects from a section in a Core Data backed UITableView doesn't trigger the selection to delete?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm having a problem managing the sections in my Core Data backed UITableView, using an NSFetchedResultsController.

My table view can have 2 sections, the first is a static section and is displayed conditionally. The second section is being populated with the fetched results controller. I'm using the following to determine how many sections to display. If I delete all of the fetched objects in the second section, I would expect that section to be deleted as well.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)aTableView
{
 NSInteger numberOfSections = 0;
 if (self.locationEnabled) numberOfSections++;
 if ([[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] lastObject] numberOfObjects]) numberOfSections++;
 return numberOfSections;
}
```

The problem with this approach is that this datasource method is informing the table that it should be displaying 1 section because there are no fetched objects remaining, but removing the last object never triggered a deletion of the section through the fetched results manager delegate methods.

How do I trigger a section deletion to avoid receiving UIKit inconsistency errors?

**Edit**: I should point out that I have sectionNameKeyPath set to nil since the results don't share anything in common to section by.